# Changing USB configurations/interfaces on the fly; initiated by the device

Tags: embedded, usb, midi

I'm working on a USB MIDI device that will function as the receiver for a wireless system. This device will communicate bi-directionally though a radio module with the transmitter, a separate piece of hardware that runs in USB host mode.

The receiver will be plugged into a PC. MIDI devices plugged into the transmitter need to show up on the PC as MIDI ports. Since the transmitter supports a USB hub, there can be multiple devices plugged in.

There are two requirements that I'm not 100% how to meet:

1.) The MIDI port names on the PC end need to reflect the name supplied by the USB device plugged into the transmitter so that it's clear which device the port is for.

2.) The set of MIDI ports on the PC needs to update when devices are plugged/unplugged from the transmitter. This is the crux of the question: is there a way to update the available USB interfaces/MIDI jacks *initiated by the device*?

The brute force way of doing this would be to completely reset the receiver any time it receives a message from the transmitter that there's been a change (on reset,the receiver would then poll the transmitter for current devices and supply the updated info when the host PC re-enumerates).

The transmitter/receiver hardware are both based on PIC32MZ MCUs (no RTOS). I'm good with writing the USB code to get the host/receiver end to do whatever. The question is about how, at the level of the USB protocol, to do this.

Also, just to be clear: The transmitter/receiver communication will be an ad-hoc protocol and the receiver will set up all its USB configuration data itself; the idea isn't to attempt to seamlessly enumerate devices over the wireless link.

Comment: So, it will be some kind of USB hub with wireless downstream ports? Did I get it right?

Comment: The "transmitter" will be an embedded USB host with either an embedded or external hub. The wireless part of the system will be a separate protocol independent of USB.

Answer (score 0):

To show the port names on the PC, just copy the USB descriptor strings over to the transmitter.

The only way for a USB device to change its configuration is to reset itself, as if it had been unplugged, and to let the host re-enumerate it. So the only way to prevent multiple devices from interfering with each other is to have multiple (virtual) USB devices on the receiver. If your hardware does not support this, then you cannot avoid the reset.

Comment: Yeah, I had kind of come to this conclusion after looking into it some more. What I'm seeing is that a hub can update its status to the host for new port status, and the USB stack on the host can request an updated configuration from the device, but the device can't proactively tell the host that its configuration is updated without a USB reset.